# Onepage Checkout - No place to enter credit card information

Tags: checkout, paypal, paypal-express

If I select the Credit Card payment method I get a message that I will be required to enter my credit card details after the order is placed.  However, when I click place order, I am taken to an order confirmation page with a confirmation number and no place to enter payment details.

Please help!

Comment: What Credit Card module do you use? What checkout do you use? What theme do you use? You have to provide A LOT more informations, so we can help. Is the credit card field in the HTML and only not visible?!